# ConfigArgParse ignores abbreviated options?

Tags: python, configuration, argparse

my config.ini:

```
banana=original_banana
```

if I run with full argument name, I get the expected result:

```
python test_configargparse.py --banana new_banana
new_banana
```

if I run with abbreviated argument name (`--ban` instead of `--banana`), I get unexpected behaviour:

```
python test_configargparse.py --ban new_banana 
original_banana
```

code for test_configargparse.py

```
import os, configargparse as ap
parser = ap.ArgumentParser(default_config_files=["config.ini"])
parser.add_argument('--banana',dest='banana')
options = parser.parse_args()
print(options.banana)
```

versions = `ConfigArgParse==0.13.0`, `Python 2.7.10`

is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?? it's a very basic feature in a very established module...

NOTE: this feature is explicitly documented in https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

> allows long options to be abbreviated to a prefix, if the abbreviation is unambiguous (the prefix matches a unique option)

Comment: @Chris_Rands - I did change the flag!! `--ban new_banana` is abbreviated form for `--banana new_banana`

Comment: @Chris_Rands - note that argparse understands this abbreviation, because if I just type an unknown option `python test_configargparse.py --bazinga new_banana`, I get `error: unrecognized arguments: --bazinga`

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know this, but it looks like `allow_abbrev` was added in Python 3.5 and you're using 2.7

Comment: @Chris_Rands - thanks, but I'm not interested in disabling `allow_abbrev`, I'm interested in keeping this functionality **without the bug** :)

Comment: Sounds like it's a `argparse` feature that `ConfigArgParse` doesn't support.  Anything in its docs?

Comment: One thing to note: your version information (thanks for giving it!) says python 2.7, and the documentation you reference is python 3. On the other hand, argparse had the same statement in the old doc, so I'd bet on what @hpaulj said.

Comment: @hpaulj - I have no problem with configargparse not supporting abbreviations - if it would have failed and said `unrecognized argument: --ban`, that would be fine. I DO have a problem with it NOT failing and behaving unexpectedly

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in `ConfigArgParse`. When it loads options from the config file, it discards any option that is [already on the command line](https://github.com/bw2/ConfigArgParse/blob/0.14.0/configargparse.py#L490-L491).

```
discard_this_key = already_on_command_line(
    args, action.option_strings)
```

The bug is that [`already_on_command_line()`](https://github.com/bw2/ConfigArgParse/blob/0.14.0/configargparse.py#L898-L903) only checks for complete argument names, not prefixes.

```
def already_on_command_line(existing_args_list, potential_command_line_args):
    """Utility method for checking if any of the potential_command_line_args is
    already present in existing_args.
    """
    return any(potential_arg in existing_args_list
               for potential_arg in potential_command_line_args)
```

That leaves two copies of the argument in the list, with the config file's value second. `ArgumentParser` takes the second value.